# Showing a fix boundary box to capture image

Tags: ionic-framework, camera, cordova-plugins

My ionic appp is to take pictures of business cards. as 99% of the business cards are landscape style so users tries to change the camera orientation to landscape mode as well. This is a natural behavior.

However, i want to avoid that and one way is to show a rectangle while camera is open (width equal to screen width and a 3:2 aspect ratio for height)

This will make life easy as users wont try to change the camera orientation.

I was looking into camera plugin which uses code like

```
 this.camera.getPicture({
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      quality: 25,
      correctOrientation: true,
        allowEdit:false,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
  }).then(async(imageData) => {
        //console.log("image data is:" + imageData) 
    // imageData is a base64 encoded string
      var base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
```

I was trying targetWidth and height but that does not draw that box like i have seen in many other apps.

there are other plugins like cropperJs but seems they let u crop the image after taken which not what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **camera-preview-plugin** instead of camera for that :

```
const cameraPreviewOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: window.screen.width,
  height: window.screen.height,
  camera: 'rear',
  tapPhoto: true,
  previewDrag: true,
  toBack: true,
  alpha: 1
}
```

[Ionic Camera Preview](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera-preview)